# How is interest based advertising implemented technically?

Tags: cookies, web, ads

(I am not looking for any code sample, just a high level understanding of how things get implemented).

So, I was in a site blinds.com finding the price for a 60" blind. I didn't purchase. Then a couple of days later I was at a very different site (Yahoo or something) and noticed an Ad for 60" blinds from blinds.com!

This I understand is "Interest based advertising". But, how is this technically done? If a cookie was created when I was browsing blinds.com with my browsing history, that cookie would not be accessible from Yahoo.com anyway right?

Answer (score 1):

So you're right, Yahoo.com would not be able to read the cookies set by blinds.com as these are first party cookies and only the "owning" domain can read its own first party cookies.

The secret here are what are known as "third party cookies" - i.e. cookies that are set by a third party and not the site you're looking at.  So an ad network (Google, Yahoo, Facebook, and others) might have had a tracking pixel or tracking script on blinds.com which set a "third party" cookie that recorded that you looked at 60" blinds.

Lets break that down into a step by step:

1. Advertiser site (e.g. blinds.com) puts a tracking pixel/tag/script on their site from the advertising network (lets call it fake-ad-network.com)
2. When you visit the advertiser's site, your browser loads the tracking pixel/tag/script from fake-ad-network.com (as it is included in the publisher's site).
3. To load the tracker your browser makes a HTTP call to fake-ad-network.com, which causes a cookie to be set on your browser from fake-ad-network.com (unless your browser is set to ban this).  **This is the third party cookie** that is used to record what you looked at.
4. You browse around as usual.
5. Some time later you visit another web site that has an ad unit (the actual slot on the page where the ad goes) on it from fake-ad-network.com
6. Your browser makes a HTTP call to fake-ad-network.com to load the ad (just like your browser would do for any other javascript or image file), during which it dutifully sends the cookie that was set way back when we were on the advertiser's site.
7. fake-ad-network.com reads the cookie information and picks an ad that is appropriate for that cookie.
8. fake-ad-network.com responds with an ad which is then displayed on the page you're viewing.

Hope that helps clear it up.